# Drop In Drop Out System with Input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm trying to code a drop in drop out system with input. Basically i have 2 sprites and im trying to swap between controlling each one. Right now I have a button i press and it switches which sprite is active however it does not let me show the animations for the other sprite and i can't control it. It also makes the other sprite that i'm not swapped to go off screen. I need both sprites to stay on screen and be able to press a button and and be able to control the other with the same input. If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated i couldn't find anything about it on google considering this is a very specific problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please read [ask] and provide a sample of your code in a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: Please pay attention to tag descriptions.  [rpg](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rpg/info) explicitly says, please DO NOT use this tag for role playing games.  RPG is a programming language used primarily by professional programmers on IBM systems.